# Перекодировать CP866 в UTF8

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, cp866

Получаю в своём консольном приложении QString в качестве аргумента командной строки. Консоль работает на CP866, поэтому сделал вывод, что QString, который я получаю находится в той же кодировке. Однако, если в качестве аргумента передать кириллицу, то я получаю что-то вроде: "????.???". Пытался перекодировать в нужный мне UTF-8:

```
QByteArray encodedString = fileNameOut.toLocal8Bit();
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP866");
QString string = codec->toUnicode(encodedString);
QTextCodec *utfCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
fileNameOut = QString::fromLocal8Bit(utfCodec->fromUnicode(string));
```

Но это не дало результата. На выходе было что-то вроде смеси проявляющийся кириллицы и кракозябр.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перекодировать?

Comment: а не логичнее было бы установить кодировку в консоли на utf-8?

Comment: да и зачем вам qt в консольном то приложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует в самом начале, еще до парсинга командной строки, вызывать   [setCodecForLocale](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForLocale) и передать туда cp866. Тогда у вас заработают методы `toLocal8Bit` / `fromLocal8Bit` и строки будут в верной кодировке.

Comment: спасибо! помогло!